# This code shows the image in a image viewer with save file or openwith. Actually i want to ask only open with for users what i do?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$img=$_GET['im'];
$im="http://localhost/proj1/images/PICS/$img";
$contents= file_get_contents("$im");

$output_file = 'image.jpg';
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $output_file);
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
//header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($contents));
echo $contents;
exit();
?>
```

Comment: The Save or Open dialog is a browser implementation detail that is not controllable through server code.

Comment: I'd really like to hear the rational for this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have that choice. If you specify `Content-Disposition: attachment`, the browser will *download* the file. How exactly the browser does this depends. Safari or Chrome will simply download the file to disk **without any prompt at all**. Other browsers happen to ask. You can't control it.

Comment: There is an option to make chrome ask you where to save the file.

Comment: @naveen PHP ***2.6***? That's not a typo? Also, as I said, ***you can't make the browser display only "open".***

Comment: @deceze thanks , but i need one alternative methode for opening an image just asking only openwith no need of  save